# What is the difference between src="{{media url='...'}}" and src="{{view url='...'}}", when to use which one?

Tags: magento2

As you know, there are 2 ways to add an image to the email template. 
syntax:

```
1. <img src="{{view url='My_Module/images/image.png'}}">

2. <img src="{{media url='My_Module/images/image.png'}}">
```

Please let me know about the difference between **src="{{media url='...'}}"** and **src="{{view url='...'}}"**

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can upload images at the `module` level or `theme` level inside the `web/images` folder and use the below code inside the email template for getting these images.

   ```
   <img src="{{view url='My_Module/images/image.png'}}">
   ```
2. These is called `Dynamic Media URL`. The dynamic media URL is a relative reference to an image or other media asset

   ```
   <img src="{{media url='My_Module/images/image.png'}}">
   ```

Comment: Thank you @DhirenVasoya 
One more question, which one should we use?

Comment: Better you can use view url. If answer help please upvote and accept as solution. so it will help other in community.